# Indefinite review button's indicator badge

Tags: discussion, bug, top-bar

Badges are meant to notify a user of something, and once a user acknowledges the notification, the badge should be removed - or at least that's my understanding.

That said, I'm not sure if this is a bug, or expected behavior, but my review badge never resolves; I've clicked it to enter the review queue, and I've even entered each queue individually (Help, Triage, etc.), refreshed my browser, however the badge remains, telling me I have things to review!

I don't expect I'd ever be able to resolve all of these issues, therefore it seems this view badge will stick around indefinitely. Expected?

[image: my review badge]

Comment: If you can still review it's still going to give you a number.  That's the way it works.  It doesn't go away like post notifications until you can no longer review.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. Maybe the new UI made this more noticeable, but I just don't recall always seeing a number there. Oh well!

Comment: Watch your terminology. 'Round here, [badges](http://stackoverflow.com/badges) mean something specific.

Comment: I'd like to request that the number on the review icon either go away or have an option to hide it. When it was on the other side of the screen from the inbox, it was easier to ignore it, but now it keeps attracting my attention when I don't want it to, because I have to spend more effort parsing that the number is indicating review queues and not inbox messages.

Comment: @Amber There's another post request that feature, and @TinyGiant posted a custom style workaround [in a comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343816/how-can-i-hide-review-notifications#comment448045_343816): `.indicator-badge.js-unread-count._reviews { display: none }`.